# Length error while creating a dfn function in APL to check for anagrams

Tags: string, computer-science, string-length, anagram, apl

I am a beginner in APL and am writing a dfm function to check whether two strings are an anagram of one another. The method I thought of was:

```
{⍵[⍋⍵] ≡ ⍺[⍋⍺]}
```

However, it returns `0` for `'ALBERT EINSTEIN'` and `'TEN ELITE BRAINS'` that are anagrams. I tried to check why:

```
     a ← 'ALBERT EINSTEIN'
     b ← 'TEN ELITE BRAINS'
     a[⍋a] ≡ b[⍋b]
0
     a[⍋a]
ABEEEIILNNRSTT
     b[⍋b]
ABEEEIILNNRSTT       
     a[⍋a] = b[⍋b]
LENGTH ERROR           
     a[⍋a]=b[⍋b]
```

Is it because the second rearrangement seems to have a leading space? Why does that happen? Can anyone suggest a way I can make this program work?

Comment: You probably need to filter out the spaces using something like `(⍵≠' ')/⍵`

Comment: For fun, I asked about this on the J programming language mailing list and got this response from Henry Rich: `-:&(/:~ @: (-.&' '))`.

Comment: Is it OK to ask for help with questions on the Dyalog APL Challenge?

Comment: I would hope that it is ok since I wanted clarification on an error rather than a solution to the question. However I will be careful in the future to think more about the problem and ask a more specific question and include if it is for a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, you would need to filter out the spaces from the vectors you're comparing. This is because your vectors will have different lengths after grading up, since one of them has an extra space.

One solution could be:

```
'albert einstein'{(a b)←(⍺~' ')(⍵~' ')⋄a[⍋a]≡b[⍋b]}'ten elite brains'
```

The first part of the code, `(a b)←(⍺~' ')(⍵~' ')`, assigns `⍺` and `⍵`, without spaces `(~' ')`, to `a` and `b` respectively. Then, you can just compare the vectors the same way you're doing now.

You can check the output of the code above on [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBOqJOUmpRSUKqZl5xSVAQr1aI1EhSfNR2wSNR7276tQV1DWBjK1gxqPulsToR73dibGPOhcmgVhJsbXqJal5Cqk5mSWpCklFiUBT1AE)